# JSON parsing (strings with space) issues on snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run the following query on a snowflake table and it works.

```
SELECT distinct "Book Name." 
from TEST.BIZ.VIEW_BOOK 
WHERE "Created on" >= '2023-10-27T21:33:02' 
or "Finally accepted" >= '2023-10-27T21:33:02';
```

I am trying to get the same info form another table where the data is in JSON format: It does not work.

```
SELECT distinct "Book Name." 
from TEST.RAW.VIEW_BOOK 
WHERE PAYLOAD_JSON:"Created on" >= '2023-10-27T21:33:02' 
or PAYLOAD_JSON:"Finally accepted" >= '2023-10-27T21:33:02';
```

Comment: Hi - what does “it does not work” actually mean? Is there an error message or does it just return no rows? Please update your question with sample data for your table

Comment: I do not see anywhere in your JSON parsing where you are casting the object to a data type.  So, you are comparing an object to a string (which looks like a date, but is a string).  Try casting both of them to a date, or at least the object in your JSON to a string, so the comparison has a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment above, this should help:

```
SELECT distinct PAYLOAD_JSON:"Book Name."::string
from TEST.RAW.VIEW_BOOK 
WHERE PAYLOAD_JSON:"Created on"::string >= '2023-10-27T21:33:02' 
or PAYLOAD_JSON:"Finally accepted"::string >= '2023-10-27T21:33:02';
```

The reason you are seeing odd results is that your JSON parsing results in an object, not a string.  You need to explicitly cast that to a string in order to compare it to a string.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I get the following error:
Error: invalid identifier '"Book Name."'

Comment: I assume you have a column by that name in your table?  It's an odd column name, but it's what you had in your question sample.

Comment: Yes I have. As I mentioned in the above, the first query works and when I try to parse JSON, I get issues.

Comment: Do you have a column in the table with that name, or are you looking for values inside the `PAYLOAD_JSON`?  Without providing the table definition in your question above, it's very hard to determine what `TEST.RAW.VIEW_BOOK` looks like.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect what it'd look like if your "Book Name." was an attribute in `PAYLOAD_JSON`.